# How do I decrease page spacing for vertical scrolling in Moon+ Reader?

Tags: ebook-reader, ebooks, moon-reader

I reading a manga in Moon+ Reader with vertical scrolling enabled and there is a large amount of blank space between the pages. Is there a way to decrease the blank space between pages?

[image: ebook with blank space between pages]